# Should a OGC compliant WFS service have a POST method in the GetCapabilities file?

Tags: wfs, web-service, ogc, getcapabilities

I am trying to integrate a WFS service from a software provider into another software provider's mapping application.

After investigating, the receiving software supplier has said that the WFS service requires a POST method in the GetCapabilities file for the WFS service.

Currently, the WFS service only allows a GET method:-

```
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="path to service here"/>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
```

But the receiving software provider has stated that the GetCapabilities must also include a POST method as below:

```
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="path to service here"/>
<ows:Post xlink:href="path to service here"/>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
```

Must a POST method be included for the WFS service to be compliant? Is it OGC compliant with just a GET method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check of the [standard](https://www.ogc.org/standard/wfs/) shows it says:

> HTTP supports two request methods: GET and POST. **One or both** of these methods may be defined for a particular web feature service and offered by a service instance. The use of the Online Resource URL differs in each case. Para 6.3.1

my emphasis, and a look at the [Schema](https://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsOperationsMetadata.xsd) shows that `<ows:HTTP>` contains an unbounded choice of Gets/Puts

```
<choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <element name="Get" type="ows:RequestMethodType">
    <element name="Post" type="ows:RequestMethodType">
 </choice>
```

So your server is valid and the client is broken.

Comment: WFS 2.0 gives even a third alternative "...Additionally the server shall conform to at least one of the HTTP GET, HTTP POST or SOAP conformance classes."